# Magento 2.1.0 & Google Analytics - Tracking Code or Google API?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, google-api

Where should I set (paste) the **Google API code**?

I'm using **Magento 2.1.0** version.

Answer (score 1):

Hi in Admin Section go to Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Google API where you can enable Google Analytics and enter your GA code.

Reference Link - https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-enable-google-analytics-in-magento-2/